# Question about scheduled reporting in professional edition

Tags: reporting, professional-edition, scheduled

I see that the limitations are: 
Scheduled reporting in PE says 1 per hour *
*Up to a possible max of 200, total.

Need a little help clarifying what that limit means. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says, you can have up to two hundred scheduled reports, in any reasonable combination of daily, weekly, and monthly combinations, but only *one* of those may run at a certain clock hour during the day. For example, if you schedule a report to run on Tuesdays at 2PM, no other report can run during that window. The system generally prevents you from scheduling conflicting schedules. Going back to the prior example, you could no longer schedule a report to run every second Tuesday of the month at 2PM, because it would conflict with the existing schedule, but you could have it run at 3PM, because it's an hour later. If you schedule only daily reports, you have an actual physical limit of 196 scheduled reports (because that's all the hours in a week), but with a combination of weekly and monthly reports, you'll be able to schedule at most 200 reports, with no more than 196 reports being emailed each week.